# Return values from eclipse plug-ins through extension points?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

i've got an Extensionpoint here which points to an interface:

```
public interface IModelProcessor {

    public void processModel(Object diagramModel);
}
```

So, each plugin which wants to usw that Extensionppoint has to provide an IModelProcessor with processModel(Object diagramModel). My Question is:

How can I now get return values from eclipse plug-ins, which implement this Extensionpoint? I could of course use an return value, somethin like this:

```
public ReturnContainer processModel(Object diagramModel);
```

But since not every plug-in will deliver a return value, I'd had to make the convention, that plug-ins should return null in this case, which is in my opinion rather dirty.
What you think about that:

```
public void processModel(Object diagramModel, Observer returnObserver);
```

So, each plug-in which wants to deliver return values can register that Observer (ofc, the plug-in would have to be Observable) and call the update method on it. What you think about that?

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on how you want your contract to look like.  In general I feel that using return values is more intuitive than using the Observer option you mentioned.  Normally I would use return values, and throw exception when errors happen.  You could also have every plugin return an object, even if said object is "empty".  There's nothing special about returning values from plugins, as long as all plugins have access to the class which you're meant to return.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options I can think of.

How about adding a `getMyValue()` method to the interface. It would then have to default to returning null through an abstract superclass. In cases where you do have a value to return, the class would overload the get-method and return a valid value.

It's pretty common in Eclipse to use abstract superclasses in this way to set default handling of methods for subclasses that dont use them.